# Update XML document using Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

On the internet I am finding a lot of examples of how to achieve this functionality, however none of them seem to work in my case. I have an string containing XML data, and I know what the XPath of the result should look like. Say for example I have an xml structure looking like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <m:parent xmlns:m="http://www.somescheme">
      <doc:header xmlns:doc="http://www.somescheme">
        <doc:documentId>137</doc:documentId>
        <doc:documentDescription>Some Description</doc:documentDescription>  
         <doc:task>
           <doc:id>49</doc:id>
           <doc:name>Some Name</doc:name>
           <doc:description>Some Task Description</doc:description>
           <doc:outcome/>
           <doc:dueDate/>
           <doc:priority>50</doc:priority>
          </doc:task>
        </doc:header>
        <m:otherinfo>234324</m:otherInfo>
      </m:parent>
```

Say for example I need to access and update otherInfo the XPath would be 'm:parent/m:otherInfo' which I should be able to read and set. For doc:outcome it would be 'm:parent/doc:header/doc:task/doc:outcome' This is a value I need to set at runtime.

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(
        new InputSource("data.xml"));

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//m:parent/doc:header/doc:task/doc:outcome", doc,
        XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The code should be something like above, however I am not getting results,

Can you point out what I am missing ?

Kind Regards
Max

Comment: Define "I am not getting results".

Comment: Consider the possibility that the schema allows many `doc:header` elements

Comment: Definition: I am not getting an NodeList as an Result of the expression, hence I can not itterate over the possible nodes in the list and update then, @gknicker That could be true, hower when I use getattribute or element on just one of the values I do get a response, it wouldnt always be safe to asume that the first is the only correct value found

Comment: Note: invalid XML `<m:otherinfo>234324</m:otherInfo>`: begin tag case doesn't match end tag case otherinfo/otherInfo

Comment: Noticed it too late, had to modify some values before posting it here, in the real xml proper start and end tags are used

Comment: Did you register a `NamespaceContext` with your `XPath` instance? Without that, the XPath evaluation doesn't know, what the `m` and `doc` prefixes  in your XPath expression are.

Comment: Then how is it possible that I can access individual values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do two additional things before you can evaluate XPATH expressions with namespaces.

1. The `DocumentBuilderFactory` instance is not namespace aware by default. So you have to call `setNamespaceAware(true)`.
2. Create your own implementation of the interface [`NamespaceContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html) and pass it to your `XPath` instance.

Here a simple `NamespaceContext` implementation as a static inner class. Only the `getNamespaceURI()` method is implemented here. (*See this IBM developerWorks article for more details and alternative implementations: [Using the Java language NamespaceContext object with XPath](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-nmspccontext/index.html?ca=drs-))*

```
static class MyNamespaceContext implements NamespaceContext {
  @Override
  public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
    if(prefix == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } else if(prefix.equals(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX)) {
      return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
    } else if(prefix.equals(XMLConstants.XML_NS_PREFIX)) {
      return XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI;
    } else if(prefix.equals(XMLConstants.XMLNS_ATTRIBUTE)) {
      return XMLConstants.XMLNS_ATTRIBUTE_NS_URI;
    } else if(prefix.equals("m")) {
      return "http://www.somescheme";
    } else if(prefix.equals("doc")) {
      return "http://www.somescheme";
    } else {
      return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
}
```

Here the part with the `DocumentBuilderFactory`:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
Document doc = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(
    new InputSource("data.xml"));

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new MyNamespaceContext());
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(
    "//m:parent/doc:header/doc:task/doc:outcome", doc,
    XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The two namespace prefixes are actually linked to the same namespace URI. In fact you can use only one prefix in your XPATH expression like `"//doc:parent/doc:header/doc:task/doc:outcome"` and you don't need to declare both in your `NamespaceContext` implementation.

Comment: Thank You, fixed my problem. //m:parent/doc:header/doc:task/doc:outcome works now